# JSDoc3 でUMLのクラス図を出力する方法はありますか？

Tags: javascript, uml

JSDoc3を使っています。
JSDocタグ等からUMLクラス図を出力する方法を調べているのですが、見つけられませんでした。良い方法は無いでしょうか？

調べたこと：
* [js/uml](http://gaertner-network.de/jsuml/) は、JSDocツールではなくEclipseプラグインだったので諦めました(Eclipseを使っていないので)。
* JSDoc3で使える[Markdown plugin](http://usejsdoc.org/plugins-markdown.html) は、[marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked)というパーサを使っているらしいですが、これにもUMLを出力するような機能は無さそうでした。